# How to convert json to java object during camel routing

Tags: json, apache, apache-camel, ibatis

I am using camel and sending json string via activemq and want to persist the received object in database using ibatis. I would like to know how to convert json to java object during camel route.

from("jms:queue:TestQueue").bean(new SomeBean())
                .to("ibatis:User.insert");

Any suggestions would be useful in converting json to java object or directly passing json to ibatis.

thanks
Lokesh

Answer (score 0):

I think yo are getting default values due to this last bit: .bean(new SomeBean())